# SIGABRT error on device but not on simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sigabrt

my app always gets a sigabrt error when trying to start up.  Being the xcode noob that I am, I don't know what to do.  If anyone could help that  would be great.

main.m

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MW3_Cheats__Free__2AppDelegate class])); // <---  ERROR IS ON THESE LINES
```

Note: The app works find on the iOS Simulator, but not on the iPhone.

THREAD:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1704) (Fri Jul  1 07:12:53 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty 
/dev/ttys001
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-1091-55
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x0]
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x0]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Couldn't register com.webs.appsbyalec.MW3-Cheats--Free--2 with the bootstrap server.
Error: 
unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is
hung in the debugger.(gdb)
```

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question. The error lays in previous lines of the stack trace, even when XCode points to that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your code is supported by device iOS.

Comment: At first I run on my device, but now its not working . Please help me.